# Laravel 5.1 - Dreamhost VPS - Always getting 404 exception

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, laravel-5.1, vps

I have been breaking my head for the last two days now and still don't have a solution. All routes in my Laravel 5.1 are throwing a NotFoundHttpException.

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

**Some additional info**

- Both example.com and abc.example.com have web directory set to
  /home/username/example.com/myproject/public
- I have a .htaccess file inside the public folder which looks like

  Options -MultiViews

  ```
  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  ```

As Image: 
 [image]

- Debugbar is showing the following error:

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. I have tried almost all solutions found on Google. None worked.

Answer (score 0):

So after fighting tooth and nail to resolve this, I decided to take a different approach and to my relief, IT WORKED!

1. Rather than deploying inside a "myproject" folder, I copied all Laravel files directly under example.com. So if you're cloning your repository (as I was), I manually copied files one level up.
2. Created the proper .env file
3. Ran the following commands in order:

   **composer dump-autoload**

   **php artisan config:cache**

and voila! things were up and running!

**Now ... some other imporant things to note.**

If you're using subdomain routing, you have to setup your domain such that it doesn't put the www. In my case, http://example.com was becoming http://www.example.com and my controller actions were failing. I am sure there is a work around for this. Will update this answer, if I find and answer.